# Fast + good Quality Image Resizing Algorithm in C# without using GDI+ / WPF

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, image, resize

I need to resize a lot of images without losing to much quality.
Using PresentationFramework (WPF) is pretty fast, but quality is poor.
Using GDI+, it's good quality, but locked to UI-Thread -> singleCored. :-(
Is there a good and fast algorithm combining speed and quality in one piece of code? ;-)

Comment: Have you looked at the several "how do I resize an image in .net" question here on SO already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDI+ (a.k.a. `System.Drawing`) doesn't need the message pump and will happily work on multiple threads; only real controls do - you can even use `Bitmap` in a console application (which doesn't have a message pump).

Thus, for instance, you could do the following (I have tested this):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles("C:\\MyImages", "*.jpg"))
    {
        // Spawn threads.
        new Action<string, float>(ResizeImage).BeginInvoke(file, 0.1f, null, null);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void ResizeImage(string filename, float scale)
{
    using (var bitmap = Image.FromFile(filename))
    using (var resized = ResizeBitmap(bitmap, 0.1f, InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic))
    {
        var newFile = Path.ChangeExtension(filename, ".thumbnail" + Path.GetExtension(filename));
        if (File.Exists(newFile))
            File.Delete(newFile);
        resized.Save(newFile);
    }
}

public static Bitmap ResizeBitmap(Image source, float scale, InterpolationMode quality)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    // Figure out the new size.
    var width = (int)(source.Width * scale);
    var height = (int)(source.Height * scale);

    // Create the new bitmap.
    // Note that Bitmap has a resize constructor, but you can't control the quality.
    var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);

    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        g.InterpolationMode = quality;
        g.DrawImage(source, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
        g.Save();
    }

    return bmp;
}
```

**Edit:** According to [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/26ac55ee-4763-43e5-971d-dd39e1514ab7) it seems as though System.Drawing has a global lock; especially with `DrawImage()` (although keep in mind, this is not because of the message pump). Unfortunately the only way to get multithreaded access would probably be to use [DirectX/SharpDX](http://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/) and create the device with multithreading enabled; create some backbuffers and do the resizing there - you can then tweak the minification/maxification filters. I am not sure if you can `Draw()` from multiple threads in DirectX - but even if you can't you should be able to get way more throughput from it (even on a single thread).

Comment: Sorry Jon, you're making a lot of threads but at least at g.DrawImage it's locked to a single Core. (pretty good visible on 4+ Core-CPUs - no more usage than 50% of the whole CPU)

Comment: @Sascha, after some more research you are 100% correct. Check the edited answer; I don't think GDI+ will cut it.

Comment: I cannot validate your edit, but maybe for some other guys it might be a clue into the right direction. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason not to open a separate message pump for that, on a separate thread, which simply means you can do that in 100 threads in parallel ;).

I know this is a more arcane part, but there are applications that have a sparate thread per windows by implemenmting specific windows message pumps on every thread started. The same approach can be used for that. Take it as .NET UI programming 201 level.

Comment: Wish I could post the trolling answer on so many SO questions.  Unless it's handed to 'new' developers on a plate with a sample doing exactly what's needed they're often clueless.  How often do you see a good algorithm question on SO? :/

Comment: The trolling answer is the reason why some people are afraid to ask the dumb questions. Sometimes when a new developer is lost they just need someone to point them in the right direction. Doing so without the snarky sarcasm will increase the chances that they stick around and be part of the community. Basically being called an idiot will ensure that they DO NOT stick around and contribute; or if they do then they will likely treat other newcomers as they were treated. Please don't include the troll answer, even if followed by "serious content". It's the same as calling someone stupid.

Comment: Agreed, Alex -in the futureI will not anser at all.

Comment: @TomTom: Alex is basically right, but I don't think that he specifically aimed your answer. IMHO, it's rather a comment on Kieren's post.